# Test UDP Broadcast locally

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, ip, broadcast

This is for a school project so I **need** to use UDP Broadcast.

I am building a P2P app that uses only port 5000 over UDP. I need to send a discovery broadcast packet to all clients in my network.

Normally the app will be used over Hamachi but for the purpose of developing I would like to use the simplest fastest network environment so I would like to test multiple instances locally.

I discovered that it is possible to use 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.2 etc as IPs for my local instance. (Actually tested with ips from 1 to 6 and sending messages at random to each other)

I now need to use the SAME port 5000 but do a broadcast UDP

When I invoke ifconfig on the loopback interface I do not see the BROADCAST option.

Since apparently it is impossible to add the BROADCAST option to the loopback interface, what is the easiest way to have:

- 1 ip address per instance
- same port
- running locally

Should I consider using Docker or VM or some network simulator for this purpose?

Comment: Did you try sending to the broadcast address (`127.255.255.255`) for the loopback network (`127.0.0.0/8`)?

Comment: A broadcast will be limited to the local broadcast network, and you can broadcast to all the hosts on a local broadcast network, using either the network broadcast address (last address in the network) or, more commonly, the Limited Broadcast address of `255.255.255.255` that will work on any IPv4 network (you do not need to calculate the network broadcast address). You can test your application using unicast, but use the Limited Broadcast address for the final build.

Comment: @RonMaupin I wrote a quick Python script where each script listens to 127.0.0.{index} and send a broadcast to ``, `<broadcast>`, `127.255.255.255` and `255.255.255.255` but none of the other scripts get the message. I can share the code if needed.

Comment: Not all networks types have broadcast. Certainly, the IEEE protocols (ethernet, Wi-Fi, token ring, etc.) do, but others (frame relay, ATM, etc.) do not. The loopback network in your OS seems to be one of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to broadcast to all clients, maybe multicast is enough for you. And this can fullfill all the three need you mention. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast) is the definition, and [here](https://www.tenouk.com/Module41c.html) is a little example may help you.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is meant by `group broadcast` ? I am not familiar with his term

Comment: Sorry, I edit my answer to make it more clear. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think `lo0` loopback interface supports that either...
`lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536`

Comment: You don't need to insist on lo0 if using mulitcast.

Comment: if I do not use `lo0` how can I multicast to multiple instances (same port, different ip) on the same machine?